# CefSharp: download files after login to site on WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, download, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Show browser in my form:

```
browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://yoursite.com")
{
   Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
   Size = new Size(600, 600),
   Location = new Point(200, 200),
};
this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
```

I first enter my account on browser (because without login can't download file.)
How to download file by url programmatically by CefSharp and save on pc?

For example like this:

```
browser.DownloadFile("https://yoursite.com/download/public/a.zip", "D:\\a.zip");
```

Thanks

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3569

Comment: I think this has been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289428/download-file-with-cefsharp-winforms